# SSD suspected to be failing, failing to boot

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, storage

Here is the complete story. I have this ROG Strix G g531gv laptop for almost 6 months now.

specs: i7 9750h, rtx2060(mobile), intel SSD 660p M.2 nvme 512gb, 16gb 2666mhz ram, 1tb 5400 seagate HDD

Temps when playing games that's installed on the ssd was 28c on the lows and 50c if it's really hot.

The first time the drive failed(suspected) was last march 12. What happened was i was just doing things on my laptop like browsing on chrome then it slowed down slowly to a point that every action done was delayed by a minute. I hard reseted the laptop upon booting up it got stuck on the manufacturer's logo, tried waiting for an hour but it still stuck. Tried recovering with system image, didn't also work it was very slow. The only option I had was to reinstall windows. I wiped the said SSD and installed windows on it again. Used it for 2 weeks without any fuss. Then came April 7, the problem came back. Same thing happened, slow down to a point that it's not responding anymore. Re-installed windows again, this time i tried removing the HDD to narrow down the culprit. Everything was fine again until April 23, the problem came back. I reinstalled windows again but this time I tried reinstalling all the drivers and updated the firmware of the SSD. I used windows 10 check disk but no problem was found. I also used crystialdisk but also no problem was found. The problem was reproduced when i used Intel SSD Drive Tool box's Full diagnostic scan. At 56% the problem came back, slow down until it was not responding anymore. I tried waiting for it to go away for 3 hours, was thinking that it was just the full diagnostic scan that slowed the system down but it got stuck on 56% for 3 hours. Now i wiped all the drives, installed windows on the 1TB HDD so that i can still use the laptop without trouble. I am currently doing a full reformat of the SSD, after reformat im gonna try to run the full diagnostic scan again.

I already talked to the shop where i bought the laptop, still under warranty but because of the covid-19 lockdown on our area, there's nothing the shop and I can do about it at the moment. I just want to know what really is the problem. primary culprit is the SSD. second is the nvme slot of the motherboard but i dont have anything to support that theory. Sorry for the wall of text. Any help is well appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Download the Intel Toolbox software and run it, it will show health of the drive, there may be a firmware update also, there is a utility for that (same page), but Back up before flashing new firmware!>>>>>>https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/consumer-ssds/6-series/ssd-660p-series/660p-series-1-tb-m-2-80mm-3d2.html

Comment: already did that, it crashed again.